# Remove all instances of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Edit: Example - http://jsfiddle.net/JWx7z/9/*

I'm using a lightbox plugin https://github.com/premasagar/nitelite and I'm hacking it a bit to get it to behave how I want.

The lightbox is made up of two elements: the overlay (dark slightly transparent window), and the content containing window.

Normally when a lightbox is closed the overlay is faded out and removed. When opening a lightbox it is added and faded in.

However when traversing from lightbox to another lightbox this makes the transition undesirable. I have hacked it so the old overlay remains, and the new overlay is aborted if we are going between 2 lightboxes, so it is just the content window that changes.

This means of course the overlay is a seperate instance of the lightbox to the current content window. Which in turn means when I try and close the lightbox by clicking on the overlay, only the overlay is removed - leaving the content window still on my page.

```
...

$(this.overlay)
    .bind('add', function() {
        this.node
            .one('click', function(){
                lb.close();
            });
    });
```

*Note: Each instance of the lightbox is called lb.*

I can remove this window by adding an artificial click to the close button:

```
$('#lightbox p.close a').click();
```

but this has reprecussions later as some remnants of lb still exist - for example if I want to open a new lightbox it thinks a lightbox already exists and we're moving between the two, so doesn't add an overlay as it thinks there is already one there.

How can I work it so all instances of lb are closed when clicking on the overlay?

Thanks

*Edit: Code for aborting addition of overlay if coming from a lightbox*

```
...

open: function(contents, transition){
    var lb = this;
        if (transition !== 0) {
            this.overlay.add();
    } 

...
```

Comment: What is your code for when you abort the new overlay load? Can you not assign the old overlay to a variable and then remove that?

Comment: Does the overlay not have a class that you can then just call $(".class").remove(); ? That would remove every object with the class.

Comment: @lnrbob Edited above to include oepn code. I basically pass it the transition variable 0 if coming from a lightbox. The close function looks much the same.

Comment: @Byron Cobb It does and it closes the lightbox and background - but the lb object still exists after it's closed `alert(typeof lb)` = object. Which causes issues next time I want to call it.

Comment: That's quite strange, as the docs say here -http://api.jquery.com/remove/ - everything attached should be removed including events, etc... Maybe the overlay is contained in a parent which holds state?

Comment: I've added an example here http://jsfiddle.net/JWx7z/9/

Comment: @Byron Cobb This is how you suggest http://jsfiddle.net/JWx7z/12/ - but still lb exists after close!

Comment: you alert the type of lb - the first time lb isn't created, so it will not exist, but the 2nd to n times, you never unload lb, so of course it will exist. you have the var lb in your javascript, so even if you remove divs the var still exists, but when you call lightbox again, lb becomes the new nitelight instance.

Comment: To clarify, lb != <div>, lb = the object nitelight

Answer (score 0):

You can change your overlay click function to `fadeOut` the `.nitelite-lightbox-container` as well on close:

```
$(this.overlay)
    .bind('add', function(){
        this.node
            .one('click', function(){
                ...
                $(this).next('.nitelite-lightbox-container').fadeOut();
                lb.close();
            });
    });
```

[See fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JWx7z/13/)

It alerts "lb already exists" when you reopen the lightbox, however it still behaves correctly.

Comment: This works fine in the example (and is essentially the same what @Byron Cobb was saying (`$(".nitelite").remove();`). However in my real site I use the existence of lb to check if the transition is page to lightbox or lightbox to lightbox. Sure I can change how I do this and work out another way of checking what transition to use - but it slightly feels like it's cheeting/dirty as the lb object is still there in some form when the lighbox doesn't actually exist.